# Spotify Developer API - unset limit

Tags: spotify

I am using spotify api to fetch data about artists and their artwork.  URL I am refering is http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=hariharan.  When I hit this URL, I get the data in json format.  Here, the limit of the records per artist is set to 100 whereas actual num_results is 2542.

Is there any way to remove this limit and get all the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you will have to page through the results. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/